# Nothing changes when I click update

Tags: vb.net

When I click on my `Update` button the below function is called but the DB is not updating. The syntax is correct but i cannot figure it out where I'm missing something. Any suggestion?

```
Private Sub UpDateRecord()
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
    Dim cmdString As String = "UPDATE hpn " & _
                                  "SET " &_ 
                                      "Day = @Day, " & _ 
                                      "FullName =@FullName, " & _  
                                      "Balance = @Balance, " & _  
                                      "Deposit = @Deposit, " & _  
                                      "Withdraw = @Withdraw, " & _ 
                                      "CashIn = @CashIn, " & _ 
                                      "CashOut = @CashOut, " & _ 
                                      "Spend = @Spend, " & _ 
                                      "Total = @Total " & _
                                  "WHERE ID = @ID"
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
        conn.Open() 'conn.Open() before creating OleDbCommand Obj
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", TextBox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", TextBox3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deposit", TextBox4.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Withdraw", TextBox5.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CashIn", TextBox6.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CashOut", TextBox7.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Spend", TextBox8.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", TextBox9.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Me.ID)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: We'd need to see more of a description of what is going wrong. Does this code get executed at all? Try using a debugger to see if your database code is being run.

Comment: @halfer yeah all work

Comment: when i edit currrent data in gridview it not change

Comment: @YiaiYiko please open connection before `Using OleDbCommand`

Comment: @YiaiYiko you are not calling the command to exec the query

Comment: @Simo Thanks alot

Comment: @YiaiYiko i posted an answer were i fixed the code with a little explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is it supposed to update the DB if you are not calling `OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Code fixed:

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
    conn.Open() 'conn.Open() before creating OleDbCommand Obj
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deposit", TextBox4.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Withdraw", TextBox5.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CashIn", TextBox6.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CashOut", TextBox7.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Spend", TextBox8.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", TextBox9.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Me.ID)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'THIS IS THE LINE YOU WERE MISSING
    End Using
    conn.Close() 'YOU FORGOT TO CLOSE THE CONNECTION
End Using
```

This code was full of mistakes:

- It's always better to open the connection inside the right `Using`
- You weren't calling `OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` so all parameters was set but the query wasn't executed.
- You weren't closing the connection.

Comment: @YiaiYiko to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  just follow these simple steps!

Comment: Dont use `AddWithValue`, it has to infer the datatype, use `Add` to specify the datatype...

Comment: @Codexer My intention was to fix the code and help the PO. I don't know his columns type so I preferred to stay as much as I can similar with the original code

Comment: @Codexer i will try ty